# Complexity of counting words of given length in regular or context-free language

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, formal-languages

Let $L$ be a regular or context-free language over 
alphabet $\{0,1\}$.

What is the complexity of counting words of length $n$ in $L$?

Is it possible to efficiently find if for given $n$
all words of length $n$ are in $L$?

If one can construct DFA for regular language I
believe it is equivalent to counting paths in graph,
but constructing DFA might not be tractable I
suppose.

$L$ might be ambiguous.

**Added**

The language is given as grammar
and assume constructing DFA is intractable.

Comment: take a look:http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/counting-words-accepted-by-a-regular-grammar

Comment: This depends to some extent on how the language is given since as you said for a DFA this amounts to counting paths.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg edited per your comment. The language is given as grammar.

Comment: If the grammar is context free and unambiguous the Chomsky-Schutzenberger method give a system of algebraic equations. The ambiguous case is more complicated. If the language is left regular an unambiguous you get a linear system.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thank you. As I wrote I am mainly interested in ambiguous language.

Comment: A language is inherently ambiguous iff all its grammars are ambiguous. There are cfl's like that. But regular languages are never inherently ambiguous so you mean to say the grammar is ambiguous. This gets tricky.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I am not an expert on this. I expect the complexity to be #P complete.

Comment: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~maackerman/ThreeNewAlgorithmsForRegularLanEnum.pdf seems to give a polytime algorithm to enumerate lexicographically all words of length n accepted by an nfa.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks. This doesn't appear efficient if the words are about 2^1000 IMHO.

Comment: It's #P complete

Answer (score 1):

This is #P hard via counting solution to monotone DNF formula.

Let $\phi(x_1,...x_n)$ be monotone [DNF formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) on $n$ variables.

We are trying to find regular language $L$ over alphabet $\{0,1\}$
with all words of length $n$ and the words in $L$ are in one
to one correspondence with the satisfying assignment of $\phi$.

Variable $x_i$ in $\phi$ corresponds to $i$-th element in a word
$\{0,1\}^n$.

To satisfy clause $c^j$ in $\phi$, we match the indexes of the variables
in $c^j$ in a regular expression $W$ and the rest of the variables can be
arbitrary.

More formally set the regular expression
$W^j[i]=1$ if $x_i \in c^j$,
otherwise, set $W^j[i]=0 + 1$ where $+$ denotes union. (If necessary we can allow negative literal $\lnot x_i$ by setting $W^j[i]=0$

E.g. for the clause $(x_1 \land x_4)$ we set $W^1=1 \; 0+1 \;  0+1 \; 1$.

Finally, set $L = W^1 + W^2+ \cdots+ W^m$.

So far, $L$ is defined by regex. Experimentally it appears
to have NFA with polynomial size in $n$ (the grammar is obviously small).